# how can i fix this issue

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

when i run flutter run in my project, the compile failed. i got this code in verbose mode

```
ADMIN@ZIRCON-KH101 MINGW64 ~/Documents/android project/new/flutternewsapp-10/codecanyon-26536344-classic-flutter-news-app-best-for-news-blog-and-magazines/01. Flutter/classic_flutter_news
$ flutter run
Using hardware rendering with device Android SDK built for x86. If you get graphics artifacts, consider enabling software rendering with
"--enable-software-rendering".
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Target debug_android_application failed: FileSystemException: Creation failed, path = 'C:\Users\ADMIN\Documents\android project\new\flutternewsapp-10\codecanyon-26536344-classic-flutter-news-app-best-for-news-blog-and-magazines\01. Flutter\classic_flutter_news\build\app\intermediates\flutter\debug\flutter_assets\packages/cupertino_icons' (OS Error: The filename or extension is too long.
, errno = 206)
build failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 882

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full 
insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 21s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                        23.9s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

how can i fix this issues cause i already run flutter packages get, flutter clean inside my project and pass my release to stable channel

Answer (score 0):

Your File path is too long.

```
C:\Users\ADMIN\Documents\android project\new\flutternewsapp-10\codecanyon-26536344-classic-flutter-news-app-best-for-news-blog-and-magazines\01. Flutter\classic_flutter_news\build\app\intermediates\flutter\debug\flutter_assets\packages/cupertino_icons
```

this exceeds some limitations in compilers and some programs.

so simply move your project folder to something simple like `C:\Projest\`

also change the name of this folder to something shorter

```
codecanyon-26536344-classic-flutter-news-app-best-for-news-blog-and-magazines
```